# PDO Statement not pulling data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to list data from two specific columns in a table. Whenever I go to the file, it returns  a server error. When I remove the while loop, it executes perfectly, so I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Here's the error:

> Server error The website encountered an error while retrieving
>   http://dayzlistings.com/reg-whitelist.php. It may be down for
>   maintenance or configured incorrectly. Here are some suggestions:
>   Reload this webpage later. HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An
>   unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting
>   to fulfill the request.

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname','dbuser','dbpass');
            $sql = "SELECT * from wp_cimy_uef_data";
            $q = $dbh->prepar($sql);
            $q->execute();
                while($row = $q->fetchall() {
                    echo $row['USER_ID'];
                    echo $row['VALUE'];
                }
    }
$dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error from Dedicated Database!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

Comment: Server error
The website encountered an error while retrieving http://dayzlistings.com/reg-whitelist.php. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

Comment: You have a typo in the line `$q = $dbh->prepar($sql);`. Should be `prepare` instead of `prepar`

Comment: @peterm Yep fixed it but nothing. I am feeling really dumb right now. I know it has to be something easy.....

Comment: @Ryahn It should be something with the php file itself. It's not a PDO error. Show you php file where you use that code if possible (you can use [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com) for that)

Comment: @peterm http://pastie.org/private/rgso6xsqdonhpfompitb5g

Comment: Seems legit, since the difference is only in opening `<?php` tag. It's time to look in your webserver logs.

Comment: @Ryahn What does the error (apache) log say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

500 means something wrong when you interact with the server, e.g. access db.
And `$row['USER_ID']` will never work, instead you should use `$row[0]['USER_ID']`.

Answer (score 0):

isn't `fetchAll()` returns the whole table as an array?..

you don't need to while loop $row.. just do `$row = $q->fetchAll()` without while and print_r the whole array and see what you get..

and if you still wanna do while I think you may use

```
while($row = $q->fetch()){
//  rest of the code here
}
```

Also you cannot put annything between try catch..

```
try{
//code
}
$dbh = null; //**This is not allowed by the way...**
catch(PDOException $e){
  //code
```

}

Dins

Comment: Its still throwing the same error. I have another file that is connected to the same database and it works fine.

Comment: I updated the comment.. I am notr sure this will fix ur issue.. you will need to check ur apache logs for 500 error.. but just to let you know that no one can come in between try and catch...